# Port mirroiring on Openstack

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I'm using Openstack Zed on Ubuntu 22.04 deployed using MAAS and Juju. I'm trying to mirroir my traffic to an IDS instance. The option I've found so far is Tap as a Service. I've installed and configured it but my tap ports and flows stay DOWN.

I cant find any up to date deployment methods of TAAS for this architecture. Are there other options?